# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted in Cygwin terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, message-queue, lib

I am trying to run a python script in Cygwin, however I am getting this error:

```
$ python3 simulation.py probes/test1.xml
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artem/orbita-simulator/models/earth/pycontrol/program.py", line 145, in _destroy_worker
    self._request_queue.unlink()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Exception ignored in: <function Program.__del__ at 0x6ffff6247670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artem/orbita-simulator/models/earth/pycontrol/program.py", line 126, in __del__
    self._destroy_worker()
  File "/home/artem/orbita-simulator/models/earth/pycontrol/program.py", line 145, in _destroy_worker
    self._request_queue.unlink()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I am facing such a problem for the first time, so I would like to know the solution to this problem, thanks! (If I run this script on ubuntu, then everything runs perfectly)

I use Cygwin because the posix_ipc library doesn't support all functionality on windows